# PHP Combo box using Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

i trying to populate combo box using php code but not execute/show properly
code for login screen, its selecting records from branch table and put in combo button to selected by user, but it's not show properly , please check 
[image: snapshot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Visual Securas Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome To Visuak Securas</h1>
        <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "xxxxx";
        $dbname = "visual";
        // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
        ?> 

            <form class="form">
     <?php
        $sql = "SELECT branchname FROM branch";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo "<select name=\"pcid\">";
        echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {        
        echo '<option value="'.$row['branchname'].'">'.$row['branchname'].'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
     ?>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <select multiple="multiple" 
                <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: basic debugging: did you do a `view source` to see what you really generated? since you have a blank `<option size=30>` at the start of your `<select>` you shouldn't see anything in there until you hit the dropdown button.

Comment: What do you mean "not showing properly"? It's not shown in a right place or there is no proper data in the drop-down?

Comment: It's not shown in a right place, see image , text and label font different form it, pl. help i am newbie in web coding

Comment: @Prasanna Did you prepare css for it?

Comment: yes sir, i am using css,     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: well this seems more like an html question, more than PHP. But basically, if you could create an html page, and post it, we can jam it in for you with PHP. So yes, Prasanna, we can help, k? Remember **Tyler** asked for you to show us your css file. We haven't seen it, and it is not visible at all in your above HTML send-out if you will, via PHP

Comment: Thanks Drew Sir, i am newbie in this forum , pl.guide me how to attache my css files

Comment: ok I will, in Tyler's Answer, k?

Comment: Sir, i added my css file, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is currently there, I would say this is a styling issue, it appears that there is no styling being applied to your select tag. (CSS) Otherwise, it is showing in exactly the place that you have it in your code.

**Edit:**

### Chunk1: css trivially small, plopped inside head and not a link

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first styled page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #d8da3d }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
[etc.] (not shown)
```

versus the next 2 chunk combo (that is, chunk2 and chunk3 are sorta married)

### Chunk2: External css file

This is preferred way, css is reusable.
Imagine this is a css file named myStyle.css

```
body {
  padding-left: 11em;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
  color: purple;
  background-color: #d8da3d }
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 9em }
h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,
        SunSans-Regular, sans-serif }
ul.navbar li {
  background: white;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-right: 1em solid black }
ul.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none }
a:link {
  color: blue }
a:visited {
  color: purple }
address {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-top: thin dotted }
```

### Chunk3: Include myStyle.css we just saw in Chunk2

using the css styles appropriately in `<body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first styled page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
[etc.] (not shown)
```

Ok, end of Chunks. You basically need to do this as text rendered out via PHP which you are not doing. Again, note, you either do Chunk1, or (Chunk2 and Chunk3). So your issue is a styling/html/css issue.

Comment: yes sir, that's correct , can help me out how to put select styling, i goggled but didn't got any help

Comment: let's see your current css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: how can i add my css file , in this topic

Comment: post the contents of style.css into your original question please

Comment: you need to apply similar styling to your combo dropdown as you have applied to your input fields

Comment: Alright, here's the quick and dirty way. Find where it says "form input" and add in ",select" next to input so it will be "form input,select {". That will at least get you the shape and sizing of your input boxes.

Comment: Also, in your php, you could add in something like "Click to Select" in the first option that's not in the while loop, that way it's not blank and users know to click it. It should be stylized further with a dropdown arrow though.

Comment: you could ALSO add in a ",select:hover" after the "input:hover" so that it changes to white when you mouse over it, that would be neat.

Answer (score 0):

MY CSS FILE

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(85px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(85px);
          transform: translateY(85px);
}
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
          transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
  font-weight: 200;
}
form {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
form input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
form input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
form input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
form button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
form button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
.bg-bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bg-bubbles li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  bottom: -160px;
  -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
  animation: square 25s infinite;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 17s;
          animation-duration: 17s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 22s;
          animation-duration: 22s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 70%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 80%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 32%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
          animation-delay: 7s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
          animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 90%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
          animation-delay: 11s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
```